# Tensorflow Performance Does Not Improve with additional GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I'm testing the [standard benchmark for tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/benchmarks) with my desktop config as shown below.

1. Intel i7-7700k
2. Asus B250 Mining edition
3. 16 Gigabyte p106
4. 32GB memory
5. Ubuntu 16.04 `cuda` 9.0 and `cudnn` 7.1
6. `Tensorflow` 1.10 Installed

However, the results for 8 cards and 16 cards are the same.

Any idea why is this case happening?

Comment: You need to install `tensorflow-gpu` version and be sure that your system detect your GPUs in terminal: `$ nvidia-smi`.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your setup and the parameters you're using in the benchmark.

- Verify nvidia-drivers are properly working: `nvidia-smi`.
  All your GPUs should be listed there.
- Verify `tf-nightly-gpu` is installed: `pip list`. This is a requirement according to benchmark [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/tree/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks).
- While the model is training, use `nvidia-smi` again to check if there is actual GPU utilization, and how many GPUs are utilized.
- Try changing `variable_update` parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

I install tf-nightly-gpu and variable_update=independent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyZXL.jpg)